# Two groups A and B are playing a game...

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two groups A and B are playing a game.
The first group that wins 3 times is the winner.

The probability that group A will win at on game is $\frac12$ and the same thing for group B.

$X$ = The number of games until one of the groups (A or B) will be the winner.

What is the probability function of $X$? (as table).
[We know that there is only three options].

Please help me with the table of this probability function...

Thank you so much!

Here is my try after your help:

[image]

Comment: @Shaun, I edit and put my try, thank you!

Comment: You have missed the possibility that $X=0$

Comment: @Henry, but the option of $X=3$ is same as $X=0$, right? Becuase if we are at $X=0$ it means that both groups are equal...

Comment: Read the question again, please. Are you really saying that there is a positive probability that after a single game team A has won three games?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thank you! but I don't understand, where is my mistake? what is missing at the table?

Comment: Your entry for $x=1$ calculates the probability that team A won exactly one out of the first three games, same with $x=2$ and $x=3$. But this is not what is being asked.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, so how I fix it?? Thank you!

Comment: I need to multiply all the things by $2$?? @JyrkiLahtonen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be at least three games for somebody to win, and cannot be more than five as somebody would have already won.

One approach (not the most efficient in general) would be to list the possible outcomes

```
AAA
AABA
AABBA
AABBB
ABAA
ABABA
ABABB
ABBAA
ABBAB
ABBB
BAAA
BAABA
BAABB
BABAA
BABAB
BABB
BBAAA
BBAAB
BBAB
BBB
```

Those of length $3$ each have a probability of $2^{-3}$, of length $4$ have $2^{-4}$ and  of length $5$ have $2^{-5}$.

So to answer your question, just add up the probabilities for those of length $3$, and similarly those of length $4$ and of $5$.  The three probabilities should add up to $1$.

Comment: And what about if it's A or B? It doesn't matter?

Comment: @Yoar: The question is defining $X$ as the number of games played when either A or B wins, so both cases must be counted together. I recommend this approach first, because you need to understand what the question is asking. After that I suggest you look at my answer and try to understand it.

Comment: I add my new table... I hope it's correct now...

Comment: How the sum of the elements will be 1? I try but I didn't succes..

Comment: Somebody has to win eventually.  So the total probability that somebody wins at some time must be $1$.

Comment: Yes, but I try to find where is my mistake... can you help me with this? Thank you!!

Comment: For example what is $f(3)$?

Comment: $$Pr(X=3) = 2 \times 2^{-3}$$ $$Pr(X=4) = 6 \times 2^{-4}$$ $$Pr(X=5) = 12 \times 2^{-5}$$  The error in your revised table is in the coefficients

Comment: But if I want formula for those numbers i.e. with "n choose k", how do I get it?

Comment: Consider something like @user21820 's reply, so $2={(3-1)+0 \choose (3-1)}+{0+(3-1) \choose 0}$ while $6={(3-1)+1 \choose (3-1)}+{1+(3-1) \choose 1}$ and $12={(3-1)+2 \choose (3-1)}+{2+(3-1) \choose 2}$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more elegant answer than Henry's, but you need more work. Let $n$ be the number of wins that one player needs to obtain for the game to end.

Start at the single "1" at the apex of Pascal's triangle. For every game, go down one row, left if A wins and right if B wins. Notice that as long as each of A and B have less than $n$ wins, the number of games that gets to a point in the Pascal's triangle will be equal to the number at that point in the triangle. When A wins, it is because we last went left onto the $n$-th right-downward diagonal. Likewise when B wins, it is because we last went right onto the n-th left-downward diagonal. Therefore we can now easily write down all the probabilities we want. For example there are $\binom{n-1+k}{k}$ games with $n-1$ A-wins and $k$ B-wins, for any natural $k \le n-1$, and hence the probability that a game would have $n$ A-wins and $k$ B-wins would be $\binom{n-1+k}{k} 2^{-(n+k)}$.

Comment: I add new table, hope it's correct!

Comment: @Yoar: Your table does not make sense, given what Henry said in the first line of his answer.

Comment: I still don't understand... Where is my mistake? :-(

Comment: If $f$ is the probability density function of a discrete random variable $X$, $f(x)$ must be the probability that $X = x$. What are the possible values of $X$ in the first place?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, I'm little bit confuse, my table is like what Henry says, no?

Comment: can you write my please the values for $x=1,2$? I think I'll understand better at this way... Thank you!

Comment: No you did not understand your own question. Your question had defined $X$ to be the number of games that had been played when one player has won 3 games. What can $X$ be?

Comment: 3,4,5... right?

Comment: Right, so you would not be interested in knowing $f(1)$ and $f(2)$. Instead you would want to find $f(3),f(4),f(5)$. Now follow what Henry did and list on your own all possible ways the games might go, and then find the probability that the total number of games is $3,4,5$ respectively.

Comment: No it has nothing to do with the values in your table. It is your table headers.

Comment: I fix it! but the sum of all of them is not 1....:-(

Comment: Yes your values are wrong. You didn't follow Henry's method!

Comment: I try, but I don't understand where I wrong :-(

Comment: Please write me $f(3)$ and $f(4)$, I'm really don't understand...

Comment: Please tell me where I wrong...

Comment: You have a list of mutually exclusive outcomes. Each outcome has a certain probability determined by how many games it took. An outcome that took only 3 games would be more likely than one that took longer. Now all you have to do is find the probability that the outcome takes 3 games, then 4, then 5.

Comment: It's help what you right but I still not understand... how I calculate it... please tell me what is $f(3)$ it will help a lot..

Comment: You tell me what is the probability for each and every possible outcome that Henry listed. Then since the outcomes are mutually exclusive, tell me the probability that the outcome is one of those with length exactly 4. Then I will tell you whether you did it correctly.

Comment: This is what Henry wrote... it is the (the amount of them)*2^(the length).

Comment: $2*2^{-3}+6*2^{-4}+12*2^{-5}$

Comment: You didn't answer my question..

Comment: But, how did I get the $2,6,12$?? This what I don't understand...

Comment: Err.. he didn't say $2,6,12$ so where did you get those numbers from??

Comment: Ah, sorry, the 3-length has $2^{-3}$ each, the 4 - $2^{-4}$ and so on, I'm right?

Comment: Right, and where did you get 2,6,12 from?

Comment: I count the number of each length...

Comment: and $2*2^{-3}+6*2^{-4}+12*2^{-5}=1$.....

Comment: Right. That's a valid method. If you want a formula instead of counting, then you'll have to read my answer..

Comment: But how I get from your formula $f(3)$? I try and I didn't success... can you write it for me please?

Comment: Please... This Q is for a test that I'm study for, I waste to much for this... can you write me $f(3)$? it will help me a lot!!

Comment: Before trying to get the answer from anything, do you understand what I am doing in my answer? I think it is wiser to understand what you are doing in general rather than being able to get the answer to just one question.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I can't use Pascal, so I tried use the formula but I didn't understand (I had few tries) what is $n$ and what is $k$ so this why I ask for an example, it will make the things more clear...

Comment: Or you can just use Henry's method for your test and learn other methods after your test. It is not something that can be taught so quickly if you don't have a firm grasp of the foundations.

Comment: OK... Thank you for your comment.
But you can please write $f(4)$? It will helps me a lot!

Comment: Ok but you'll have to write it. If $X=4$, there are two cases, either ( 3 A-wins and ? B-wins ) or ( 3 B-wins and ? A-wins ).. Each of these two cases are mutually exclusive, and my formula gives the probability for each. So what is the sum?